# How to get rid of empty space before UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` in a `UIViewController` in a `UINavigationController` in a `UITabBarController`.

In my `UITableView`, I have section headers, and all sections have 60 pixel height. Set like this.

```
tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 60
```

My `UITableView` also have `Grouped` for style attribute.

The problem is, there is empty space above my `UITableView` and I want to get rid of it.

The problem only occurs on iPads, there is no empty space on smaller devices. (I simulated on iPad 2 and iPhone 6 respectively.) Because of this solution #3 does not work.

Some of the solutions I have tried but did NOT work:

1. `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`
2. `tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero`
3. `self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-64, 0, 0, 0)`

Does not work for all devices. Because my table already works good in some devices and this makes it go out of screen on them.

4. Setting `UITableView` style to `Plain` instead of `Grouped`.

This works, but I need my headers to be Grouped style not plain. So I can't use this.

So what are my options here? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Screenshot:[image: Ss1]
[image: Ss2]

Comment: you mean there is a space between tableview and navigationcont ?

Comment: Yeah exactly. Between UINavigationController and UITableView.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot and code/constraints that you may have used?

Comment: Added screenshots.

Comment: Try to off the isTranslucent property of both navigationBar and SearchBar

Comment: Tried that, didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to uncheck `adjust scrollview insets` property by selecting relevant `viewController` see below image:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already said I tried this and didn't worked for me in #1. But thanks anyway.

Comment: ohh, have you tried doing this using storyboard may resolves your issue.

Comment: @TheCook then i think there is some constant issue, you can share some screenshot here.

Comment: Added some screenshots.

Comment: then i guess extra space is between `searchBar` and `tableView` according to setting `scrollview insets` and if it is not then sure there is constraints issue.

Comment: Yeah seems like it, what could be the problem here tho?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128125/discussion-between-vaibhav-and-the-cook).

Answer (score 1):

Change the `UITableView`'s  `Style` property  to `plain` in interface builder, like following.

[image]

Comment: Yeah this fixes the empty space problem. But I want to keep Grouped property as I said in #4. So we need to find another alternative.